# Confused about Nitrogen listen IP address

Tags: erlang, mnesia, mochiweb, yaws, nitrogen

Am running Nitrogen 2.0.X on Windows 7 Home Premium, HP Pavilion Entertainment PC Laptop.
Nitrogen starts with inets and i have failed to change or dictate the IP address of the webserver.
Once it starts, it tells me to go to my browser and hit `http://localhost:8000` in the shell output below:

```
erl -make
Starting Nitrogen on Inets (http://localhost:8000)...
Eshell V5.8.4  (abort with ^G)
```

Hitting the link in almost all available browsers shows that page could not be found. When i ask the emulator about the ports, this is its output:

```
(motv@josh.ekampus.internal)1> inet:i().
Port Module    Recv Sent Owner    Local Address  Foreign Address State
3109 inet6_tcp 0    0     *:8000         *:*             ACCEPTING
618  inet_tcp  0    0     *:9543         *:*             ACCEPTING
637  inet_tcp  4    19    localhost:9544 localhost:4369  CONNECTED
Port Module Recv Sent Owner Local Address Foreign Address State
ok
(motv@josh.ekampus.internal)2>
```

Am having a strong thought that `inet6_tcp` means that its using `IPv6` while `inet_tcp` means `IPv4`, not very sure about this. But all in all, i cannot connect to my Nitrogen. These below are the running applications

```
(motv@josh.ekampus.internal)2> application:which_applications().
[{quickstart,"Nitrogen Quickstart",[]},
 {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","5.6"},
 {nprocreg,"NProcReg - Simple Erlang Process Registry.",
           "0.1"},
 {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.17.4"},
 {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.14.4"}]
(motv@josh.ekampus.internal)3>
```

Can someone explain why i cannot Reach my Local Nitrogen Framework by just hitting `http://localhost:8000` in the browser, given the observations above? And, how can i connect to it from my browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some guesses:

Did you try http://127.0.0.1:8000 ?

If that doesn't work, can you startup erlang with forced ip4 support (i think):

`-proto_dist inet_tcp`

Comment: The `inet6_tcp` Module indication is still appearing on local address `*:8000`, ACCEPTING, in the result of calling `inet:i().` in shell

Comment: Another possible solution would be to disable ip6 in windows 7. It's an ugly workaround until a proper solution is found http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852

Comment: Thanks @WardB, let me try that